# Python 10, on Windows how it shows this folder exists /home/appuser/temp

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python program, want to check directory exists before using it. When I check `/home/appuser/temp` folder, it returns `True`.  Since its Linux path, I expect to return False, not sure why its returning True.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exits("/home/appuser/temp")
True
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/home/appuser/temp").exists()
True
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
```

Why its returning True? How will I locate this folder on windows?

Thanks
SR

Comment: It returns `True` because Python is smart enough to know how to interpret such paths.

Comment: @ScottHunter but its invalid path in Windows, also It didn't exits. may I know how to check this properly on windows?

Comment: Actually, I get `False` if I run that from a `c:` or `d:` Is there any chance you are in a WSL window?

Comment: @JonSG I didn' t have WSL, I use `git-bash`. but running this program on Windows `PowerShell`